# Making a border of numbers in descending order in matrix

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix

I am trying to make a border around an empty matrix that is ascending and descending. I already have the top and left side which are ascending from 0 to 4, but I cannot get the right side and bottom side to go from 4 to 0. Here is the code of my for loops. I have tried about every variation to get it to work, but it either gives me an index out of bounds exception or just shows up as zeroes instead. I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

```
private static void fillBorder( int[][] matrix )
{
   for (int r=0; r<matrix.length; ++r) // left side
   {
        matrix[r][0] = r; 
   }
   for (int j=0 ; j<matrix.length; ++j) // top
   {
        matrix[0][j] = j;
   }
   for (int m=matrix.length; m>0; --m) // bottom
   {
        matrix[4][m] = m;
   }
   for (int s=matrix.length; s>0; --s) // right side
   {
        matrix[s][4] = s;
   }

}
```

Here is also a picture of what the output is supposed to look like to give you a better idea of what it's supposed to be. [picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzOUj.png)

[image]

Comment: use m>=0 and s >=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with a single `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    matrix[0][i] = i;
    matrix[i][0] = i;
    matrix[matrix.length-1][matrix.length-1-i] = i;
    matrix[matrix.length-1-i][matrix.length-1] = i;
}
```

This assumes that the `matrix` in fact is square (i.e. has the same number of rows and columns).  If not, then my code would have to change, but then again so would your problem statement.

```
for (int r=0; r < matrix.length; ++r) {
    for (int c=0; c < matrix.length; ++c) {
        System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 3
2 0 0 0 2
3 0 0 0 1
4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For your rows, you should be using matrix[0].length. The other thing is you should use the matrix dimension rather than hardcoding 4 into the code

```
   private static void fillBorder( int[][] matrix )
    {
       for (int r=0; r<matrix.length; ++r) // left side
       {
            matrix[r][0] = r; 
       }
       for (int j=0 ; j<matrix[0].length; ++j) // top
       {
            matrix[0][j] = j;
       }
       for (int m=matrix[0].length; m>0; --m) // bottom
       {
            matrix[matrix.length - 1][m] = m;
       }
       for (int s=matrix.length; s>0; --s) // right side
       {
            matrix[s][matrix[0].length - 1] = s;
       }

    }
```